# Replace a line with a specified pattern

Tags: notepad++, regex

As shown in the example, the number 1 appears in the same column in every line, and in my file, there are 6000 lines like that in total.

```
1. 1
2. 1
3. 1
4. 1
5. 1
6. 1
7. 1
8. 1
9. 1
```

I want to replace the 1s with a pattern of 1 2 3, as follows, but for all 6000 lines. Is a a way to do so non-manually?

```
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 1
5. 2
6. 3
7. 1
8. 2
9. 3
```

FYI, for some reasons, doing this in excel and thus changing my file there, which is in fact much more easier, is not okay.

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to replace the 1s with a pattern of 1 2 3

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*?)1\r\n(.*?)1\r\n(.*?)1\r\n`
- Set "Replace with" to `\11\r\n\22\r\n\33\r\n`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
1. 1
2. 1
3. 1
4. 1
5. 1
6. 1
7. 1
8. 1
9. 1
```

**After**:

```
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 1
5. 2
6. 3
7. 1
8. 2
9. 3
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)